# How do I use angular http.post and change Type 'Observavble<unknown> to a typed response?

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

I keep getting confused about how to type my HttpResponse. I'm trying to match what my api is giving me back but my typescript help in vim keeps telling me:

```
typescript: Type 'Observable<unknown>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<string | HttpErrorResponse>'.
  Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'string | HttpErrorResponse'. [2322]
```

This is what my post looks like:

```
forgotPassword(args: {studentId: string, emailAddress: string}): RxObservable<HttpErrorResponse | string> {
  const body = {
    studentId: args.studentId,
    emailAddress: args.emailAddress
  }
    console.log("forgot password", body)

    return this.http
      .post<HttpErrorResponse | string>(
        `${this.nextApiEndpoint}Authentication/ForgotPassword`,
        body,
        {}
      )
      .pipe(
        switchMap((data: string) => data),
        catchError((err) => {
          return err;
        })
      );
  }
```

I'm trying to use switchMap to make sure the data piped out is string, but I really don't need that because that is what my http response is already, a string.

Comment: You should create an interface or type that represents the response. That's what you would pass as the type to the `post` method instead of `HttpErrorResponse | string`. The return type of `forgotPassword` should be: `Observable<YourType>`

Comment: Also, I'm not sure why you're using a switchMap in your pipe... that will create yet another observable. If you're not doing any type of data transformation on the response, you can omit that.

Comment: Note that, even if you pass a type/interface to `HttpClient.post<T>`, there is no guarantee the result is a `T` (in fact, it's never a `T` if `T` is a class). The type parameter is a hint for the TS design/compile-time checking. You'll need to use `.pipe(map(data: unknown) => { return new T(unknown); }))` or similar to perform the casting manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just remove the `HttpErrorResponse` from the post and let `catchError` contain the type `HttpErrorResponse`. Also since we are not calling another API call with the previous data I swapped the `switchMap` with a `map`.

To sum it up, we don't need to add extra lines for `HttpErrorResponse` just the success return type is enough and typescript will allow this.

```
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()
export class TestService {
  nextApiEndpoint = 'google.com';
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  forgotPassword(args: {
    studentId: string;
    emailAddress: string;
  }): Observable<string> {
    const body = {
      studentId: args.studentId,
      emailAddress: args.emailAddress,
    };
    console.log('forgot password', body);

    return this.http
      .post<string>(
        `${this.nextApiEndpoint}Authentication/ForgotPassword`,
        body,
        {}
      )
      .pipe(
        catchError((err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
          throw 'error in source. Details: ' + err.message;
        }),
        map((data: string): string => data)
      );
  }
}
```

[Stackblitz Demo with no compilation errors](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-telxyj?description=An%20angular-cli%20project%20based%20on%20@angular/animations,%20@angular/common,%20@angular/compiler,%20@angular/core,%20@angular/forms,%20@angular/platform-browser,%20@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,%20@angular/router,%20core-js,%20rxjs,%20tslib%20and%20zone.js&file=src%2Ftest.service.ts&title=Angular%20Starter)

Comment: Thank you so much. That unkown on the return type on http client always throws me off.

Comment: @bradrice you're welcome, it happens!